# Why doesn't git ignore some folders that I specified?

Tags: git

I have a repo with two projects

[image]

BrainTrainerAPI is a .NET Core wep api that contains two folders /obj and /bin

but when I add them two my .gitignore

[image]

Git still tracks them for some reason. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what `git status` shows? Have you not added these folders into `git add` previously?

Comment: [please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)